# WordPress plugin for Limited days user

Tags: plugins, users

I have free demo use of my application for 10 days then use automatically disable.
Not delete.

After he pay us for using that application for 1 year we can extend that time duration.

If there is no any plugin, any snippet suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Membership](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/membership/) plugin does that pretty much out of the box, if i recall correctly. Not sure if only on the paid version, though.